# TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null

Tags: node.js, discord.js, fetch

Struggling to get this one to work now;

```
const superagent = require("snekfetch");
const Discord = require('discord.js')


module.exports = {
  name: "cat",
  category: "fun",
description: "Sends a random image of a cat",
usage: "[command]",
run: async (client, message, args, level) => {
//command
superagent.get('https://nekos.life/api/v2/img/meow')
    .end((err, response) => {
  const lewdembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("Random cat")
  .setImage(response.body.url)
  .setColor(`#00FF00`)
  .setFooter(`owo`)
  .setURL(response.body.url);
message.channel.send(lewdembed);
})
}
};
```

Throwing up this error;

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null
    at /home/runner/Manias-Bot/commands/fun/cat.js:16:22
    at /home/runner/Manias-Bot/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:212:22
```

I can see the error is with (response.body.url), but unsure how to solve this. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `snekfetch` has been deprecated, you should use `node-fetch` instead.

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/snekfetch

Secondly, the error is because `response` is `null` - almost certainly because you have an error when trying to get that resource. My guess would be `ECONNREFUSED` but you can confirm this by checking the value of `err` and `response` in your get, i.e.

```
superagent.get('https://nekos.life/api/v2/img/meow')
  .end((err, response) => {
    console.log(err, response)
  })
```

This give me...

```
[Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443] {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 443
} null
```

So as you can see - the server is refusing the request and the `response` is `null`

To fix this you should use a package that isn't deprecated and make sure you are trying to fetch a resource that you have permission/access to get.

When fetching anything - it is always a good idea to check to see if there are any errors before trying to do something with the expected result.

Comment: Oop. Appreciate that, had no idea snekfetch had been depreciated. Been through all the documentation and still missed it!